# Conditional cast from 'String' to 'String' always succeeds- Swift

Tags: swift

I'm getting these errors: Error: Conditional cast from 'String' to 'String' always succeeds and Error: Cannot assign to value: 'anchorOffset' is a 'let'

```
 let text = getTextPart()

    if let text = text as? String {// Error: Conditional cast from 'String' to 'String' always succeeds
 let lastOffset = text.lengthAsNSString()
      var updatedAnchorOffset = lastOffset
      var updatedFocusOffset = lastOffset
      if var anchorOffset = anchorOffset {
        updatedAnchorOffset = lastOffset
    }
      if var focusOffset = focusOffset {
        updatedFocusOffset = lastOffset
      } else {
        anchorOffset = 0//Error: Cannot assign to value: 'anchorOffset' is a 'let' constant
        focusOffset = 0//Error: Cannot assign to value: 'focusOffset' is a 'let' constant
      }
}
```

This is my getTextPart():

```
override func getTextPart() -> String {
    guard let textNode = getLatest() as? TextNode else {
      return text
    }
    return textNode.text
  }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to unwrap the result of `getTextPart()` as if it were an optional? It's not, it's always just a `String`.

Comment: `let` defined variables can only be set once initially and not changed. Define it as `var` instead if you want to assign another value to it later on.

Comment: `anchorOffset` only exists inside that closure

Comment: the same applies to `focusOffset`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line

`if let text = text as? String {// Error: Conditional cast from 'String'`

Change the definition of anchorOffset and focusOffset to

`var anchorOffset = something`

`var focusOffset = something`